# Margins with newlfm

Tags: margins, newlfm

How do I adjust margins with newlfm?  I've set everything I can find to zero, but there are still vast expanses of whitespace.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,stdletter,orderfromtodate,sigleft]{newlfm}

\headermarginsize{0in}
\rightmarginsize{0in}
\topmarginsize{0in}
\topmarginskip{0in}
\headermarginsize{0in}
\headermarginskip{0in}

% Some of the article customisations are relevant for this class

\name{MyName} % To be used for the return address on the envelope
\signature{My sig} % Goes after the closing (ie at the end of the letter, with space for a signature)
\address{Address \\ of \\ Sender}
% Alternatively, these may be set on an individual basis within each letter environment.

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Name and \\ Address \\ of \\ Receiver}

\opening{Dear John,} 

My Letter




\closing{Regards,} % eg Regards,

\cc{} % people this letter is cc-ed to
\encl{} % list of anything enclosed
\ps{} % any post scriptums. ``PS'' labels must be put in manually

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use the `geometry` package in order to adjust the spacing parameters

Comment: I have tried that. It does not work and is specifically proscribed by the newlfm user guide. 

"geometry
is no longer used for dimension setting. Rather, all dimensi
ons are set internally. This is done using a combination of default values, header and footer sizes and values input from the user. Theseinclude primarily the page size commands
leftmarginsize, textwidthsize and rightmarginsize."

Comment: Are you in the US? Don't forget the 'american' option to the newlfm documentclass
call at the top: \documentclass[american]{newlfm}

Answer (score 0):

I would personally advise against using [`newlfm`](//ctan.org/pkg/newlfm) specifically for this reason. Use a regular `article` document class and set your margins and style without hassle:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry,lipsum}
\geometry{
  margin=1in
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indent

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}% Remove page headers/footers

\mbox{}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l @{}}
  Address \\
  of \\
  Sender \\ \\
  \today
\end{tabular}

\bigskip % Vertical skip between sender/receiver address

\begin{tabular}{@{} l}
  Name and \\
  Address \\
  of \\
  Receiver
\end{tabular}

\bigskip % Vertical skip between receive address and letter opening

Dear John,

\medskip % Vertical skip between letter opening and letter body

\lipsum[1]

\medskip % Vertical skip between letter body and closing

\hspace*{.5\linewidth}%
Regards,

\medskip % Vertical skip between letter closing and signature start

\vspace{5\baselineskip} % Content that includes your signature, or space for it

My signature

\bigskip % Vertical skip between signature and attachment references

cc: % people this letter is cc-ed to

\medskip

encl: % list of anything enclosed

\medskip

ps: % any post scriptums

\end{document}
```

The code and accompanying output reads better together as the content flow is sequential - you don't have to put the sender/recipient and signature detail in the preamble when they could easily fit within the `document` body.

With a plain `article` class, you can use [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to set your margins as you need.

Answer (score 0):

This command will modify the top margin.

```latex
\topmarginskip{0in}
\newlfmP{topmarginskip=-1in}
```

You can use negative values if you want. You can find other pertinent commands in the [manual.](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/newlfm/manual.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with setting `\newlfmP{headermarginsize=10pt}`.