# Margin issues with newlfm class and hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, margins, newlfm

Is there a way to realign the margins with the hyperref? The bottom margin seems to be out of alignment when used with the newlfm class.

```
\documentclass[busletter,dateno]{newlfm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\namefrom{Name \\  \href{mailto:Name@email.com}{Name@email.com} }

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
Text
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

I have been unable to reset the margins. I seem to be unable to reset it with the geometry package, since it appears to already be in use in the hyperref package. Is there a way to fix this without modifying the hyperref package?

Comment: if you got an error using geometry please edit the example so it shows what you did, and also show the error you got. If I run your example it does not use `geometry` package at all and gives an error `! Undefined control sequence.
\@zfancyhead ...1\hbox to\headwidth {\fancy@reset`. The `hyperref` package does not load the `geometry` package.

Comment: I used a base install of LaTeX via MikTex and am using the default newlfm class and hyperref package. Adding a `\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}` after `\usepackage{hyperref}` appears to break things.

Comment: "appears to break things" is hard for anyone to debug, as I say please show show the exact error that you get in the log file in a code block in your question.

Comment: The above code generates a document with a top margin of 1 inch, and a bottom margin of 0.5 inch. The error after adding `\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}` is `Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex. ! LaTeX Error: Command \geometry already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.`

Comment: Your file generates an error in texlive 2018 even without geometry, but adding geometry gives the error you say, hyperref is not involved, the newlfm defines an unrelated `\geometry` command defined as `> \geometry=macro:
#1->\typeout {Command \string \geometry {items} no longer supported.}\typeout {
newlfm supports several dimensional commands. Please check the manual for detai
l.}.
l.2 \show\geometry`  so if you want to not use the `newflm`  mechanisms you can probably put `\let\geometry\relax` before including the geometry package

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to programmable typesetting.

After quite a little study into this, and starting over with a response, let's start with this, although it's probably not what you'd like to hear "first."

[newlfm may not be the best package choice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405240/170846)

Continuing, in a review of newlfm.pdf, found here, of course, [CTAN page for the newlfm package](https://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm?lang=en), came across this:

> 10.9 Usage tips
>
> As with any complex program, there are certain tips which can enhance the use of the program. Here are
>   several. If you come up with new ones, please forward them to p a u l at w u b i o s punta w u s t l punta e d u ; complete files
>   demonstrating useful ideas are the most helpful.
>
> > • geometry is no longer used for dimension setting. Rather, all dimensions are set internally. This is done
> >     using a combination of default values, header and footer sizes and values input from the user. These
> >     include primarily the page size commands leftmarginsize, textwidthsize and rightmarginsize.

So, with that in mind, did some "what if" with your MWE, and came up with this as a starting place, providing basic left/right margin control.

May be beyond where you want or need, but was (finally) able to remove the head and foot "hrules." For example, `\newlfmP{Headlinewd=0pt}`.

Then found this, also regarding removing the \hrules. *See* [Two good answers regarding removing \hrule from newlfm](https://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm?lang=en)

The focus on those `\hrules` is motivated by the thought of raising the footer `\hrule` to demonstrate where the bottom margin is.  I'm just not yet able to do that at the moment. After trying `fancyhdr` and `vmargin` pacakages, and quite a few different scenarios, I still can't show you a way to control the bottom margin for "page 2" and following.

Left and right, though, are pretty straightforward.

```
    % TexLive 2016 Mac OS X 10.5.8
    % pdfTex via TexShop
\documentclass[busletter,dateno]{newlfm}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%dspace? \dspace? from newlfm ¶ 3.6 p.6  newlfm.pdf  https://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm?lang=en
\usepackage{setspace} % to get doublespacing (to test bottom margin) -- the \dspace
%                   command from newlfm  produced a compile error
\namefrom{Name \\  \href{mailto:Name@email.com}{Name@email.com} }

%from ¶ 1.2 p.2 newlfm.pdf https://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm?lang=en

\leftmarginsize{2in} % exaggerated, for illustration
\rightmarginsize{2in} % exaggerated, for illustration

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
\doublespacing
\lipsum[26]
\lipsum[27]
\lipsum[28]
\lipsum[29]
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you probably should obfuscate the e-mail address included in your post. It is not good taste to publish an e-mail of another person, even though it is made public in a pdf documentation.

Comment: @jfbu  Good point. Which one, though?  The one in the example provided by the OP, or the one supplied in the documentation package? I'm not seeing any other, but, I agree; it's good to be very careful with email addresses.

Comment: what do you mean by the "one in the example provided by the OP"? `Name@email.com` looks obfuscated enough to me.

Comment: @jfbu  I agree.  I don't see an email in this one left to obfuscate.  I was thinking maybe you had found one that I had missed. The only other one I found was the one in the documentation, and it exists to be active.

Comment: It exist to be active in a pdf file on CTAN which is not the same thing as being on a web page.

Comment: @jfbu. Edit in process.  I see what you're saying, having previously not thought of generic access beyond the \LaTeX audience of this forum.

Comment: admittedly the README contains it too on the CTAN page...